# Concatenating a numeric matrix with a 1xn cell

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, concatenation, cell

When trying the following concatenation:

```
for i=1:1:length(Open)
    data(i,1) = Open(i);
    data(i,2) = Close(i);
    data(i,3) = High(i);
    data(i,4) = Low(i);
    data(i,5) = Volume(i);
    data(i,6) = Adj_Close(i);
    data(i,7) = cell2mat(dates(1,i));
end
```

Where all matrices but `dates` contain double values, and `dates` is a cell array with dates in the format '2001-01-01'. Running the code above, I get the following error:

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> Test_Trades_part2 at 81
            data(i,7) = cell2mat(dates(1,i));
```

The code above is tied to a master code which takes data from Yahoo Finance and then puts it in my SQL database.

Comment: you can not have strings and doubles in the same matrix. The better option would be to have everything in a cell

Comment: It did not work out to enter such a cell into the SQL database though

Answer (score 0):

A convenient way to store dates in completely numeric format is with [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html):

```
>> data(i,7) = datenum('2001-01-01');
>> disp(data(i,:))
       0           0           0           0           0           0      730852
```

Whether this is useful to you depends on what you intend to do with the SQL database.  Howeer, converting back to a string with MATLAB is straightforward with the `datestr` command:

```
>> datestr(730852,'yyyy-mm-dd')
ans =
2001-01-01
```

APPENDIX:

> A serial date number represents a calendar date as the number of days that has passed since a fixed base date. In MATLAB, serial date number 1 is January 1, 0000.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help!

I solved this issue using the following methodlogy (incorporating structs, should have thought of that .. stupid me):

```
 data = [open, close_price, high, low, volume, closeadj];
        s = struct('OpenPrice', data(:,1), 'ClosePrice', data(:,2), 'High', data(:,3), 'Low', data(:,4), 'Volume', data(:,5), 'Adj_Close', data(:,6), 'Dates', {dates});
```

This way, I enter all the values contained in the struct, circumventing the need to concatenate numeric and string matrices. Odd though, that is not allowed to have such matrices in on matrix; I would suppose that is the reason they created structs.